# solution to the recurrence relation $a_n=\frac{n}{a_{n-1}}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Is there a recurrence solution to $a_n=\frac{n}{a_{n-1}}$?  I'm wondering if it could be done in the form of an alternating series partial to $n$ or as a trigonometric function.

Comment: Use the fact that $a_{n+1} = (1 + \frac{1}{n}) a_{n-1}$.

Comment: To put anomaly's point in another way: Doing one step of the recursion gives you an inconvenient reciprocal, but doing it again flips it back again. That suggest that one should think in terms of $a_{n}$ in relation to $a_{n-2}$ rather than $a_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

For $n=2k+1$ odd you have:

$$a_{2k+1} = \frac{c . (2k+1)!!}{ (2k)!!}$$

For $n=2k$ even you have:

$$a_{2k} = \frac{(2k)!!}{c . (2k-1)!!}$$

where $c = a_1$.

This pattern can be seen by writing down the first 5-6 terms.
It should be easy to prove it by induction.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Set $b_n = \ln a_n$. Then
$b_n = - b_{n-1} + \ln n$, and we can write
$$\begin{align}
b_n &= - b_{n-1} + \ln n
= b_{n-2} - \ln (n-1) + \ln n\\
&= -b_{n-3} + \ln(n-2) - \ln (n-1) + \ln n \\
&\vdots \\
&= b_1 + \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{n-k} \ln k
\end{align}$$

Can you continue?

Comment: Erm.... why the downvote, if I may?